# When doing math on DateTime objects near New Year's Eve, the utc_year field gets set weirdly. Is this a bug?

Tags: perl, datetime

I've found some really weird behavior with the perl DateTim module.  It can easily seen below.

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(                           
    year => 1950,                                
    month => 12,                                 
    day => 31,                                   
    hour => 21,                                  
    minute => 0,                                 
    second => 0,                                 
    time_zone => "America/New_York",             
);                                                

print "UTC year: " . $dt->utc_year . "\n";        
print "UTC seconds: " . $dt->{utc_rd_secs} . "\n";
$dt->add(minutes => 1);                           
print "UTC year: " . $dt->utc_year . "\n";        
print "UTC seconds: " . $dt->{utc_rd_secs} . "\n";
```

The output of this script is:

```
UTC year: 1951
UTC seconds: 7200
UTC year: 1952
UTC seconds: 7260
```

So somehow adding 1 minute to the date 12/31/1950 21:00 'New York' results in the year jumping all the way to 1952.  I think this is probably a bug, but wanted to see if anyone had any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check the documentation to see what `utc_year` returns... oh wait, it's not documented! 
That makes it rather hard to determine that it's returning the wrong thing, doesn't it?

As you can surmise by the complete lack of mention in DateTime's extensive documentation, it's an internal method. It's used to exchange information with DateTime::TimeZone objects. It returns a rough guess of the datetime's year according to comments within.

If you want the DT in a different time zone (e.g. `UTC`), use `->set_time_zone`.

Comment: I would argue that it is exceptionally unlikely that a DateTime object on the 1950/1951 year boundary should have any value with the string "year" in its name returning a value of 1952 (particularly since that value jumps after adding 60 seconds).  So while it's true that this is undocumented, I don't think any rational developer would consider this behavior to be correct.

Comment: That's not an argument; that's a belief. You are free to believe what you want. I would like to note that there is no public method with the string "year" in its name that returns 1952 for a date in 1951.